# Twilio Send SMS Function Show 500 error in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, twilio-api, sms-gateway, twilio-php

I used the Twilio gateway for sending SMS to my customer. 
When User uses different country code for different phone numbers. It shows 500 internal server Error in laravel.

Eg : I Use +1 for Indian number it shows below error

[image]

Comment: are you using trail account of twilio?

Comment: No used live account.

Comment: Did you set up from settings, for which countries you are providing this service?

Comment: here is link to active your geolocation for services https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/settings/geo-permissions

Comment: We provide the App to all country in the world

Comment: Ok I will check it.Thanks

Comment: you need to select countries but first India has `+91` country code then why you are using `+1` for it. It also could be an issue behind this error code. here is `error codes` documentation https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors

Comment: The app used in many countries. One of the customer tries this different country code & a different phone number. that time we face this 500 internal server error

Comment: this `error returns` from `Twilio` server, if you are entering the wrong phone number to send. You need to handle it from your server-side

Answer (score 0):

Hi to be sure that the number is valid, I'd start by using can use a regular expression validation tool such as https://www.regextester.com/115665. After that, you can use [Twilio's E.164 phone number validator](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-e164), `^\+[1-9]\d{1,14}$`, in your code to be sure that the number supplied is in E.164 format, which Twilio requires.

As an aside, afaik, +91 is the Indian country code, not +1 which is for the United States of America.